# Classification of a person's name versus a company name

Tags: classification, natural-language

My current problem is that I have a long list of strings that need to be classified as either a "Person", "Firm", or "Bad Data". Some of these were human entered, so there are a bunch of misspellings and idiosyncrasies in the formatting and punctuation.

This initially doesn't seem very difficult, just look for "LLC" or "Inc", or nouns that don't commonly occur in names, eg "Insurance". The problems come with sole-proprietorships, eg "John Smith LLC", and strings that include both a person and the firm they work for, eg "John Smith/Wells Fargo".

So, can anybody point me to research on algorithms that can decide whether a string is a name? Or one that's able to sift out "Bad Data" given a training set of "Good Data"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is known under the name "Named Entity Recognition" (NER). The are many publications and readily available tools for this purpose (especially for English language).

Comment: Thanks! I feel like the problem I had here was trying to find what this problem was called in the literature. Searching google for "name classification" is not the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To complete jknappen's answer, have a look at [conditional random fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) for the NER task, and in particularly linear-chain CRF since they can be optimized accurately and their modelling suits text: the word class will depend on the local context, the word before and the word after.